# Runnable doesn't execute what should

Tags: java, multithreading

I have TIMER_funk - method which countdown to 0

I have method which pop-up new window

```
public void DialogWindowkk(String Title, String Header, String Content)  {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
    alert.setTitle(Title);
    alert.setHeaderText(Header);
    alert.setContentText(Content);
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    alert.showAndWait();};
```

And I need when firs timer starts to work, then the first window pop-up(task3). When the second timer starts to work then a pop-up new window(task4). But now works only timers. Windows don't pop up. Method works.

```
Runnable task1 = () -> {TIMER_funk(task11);};
Runnable task2 = () -> {TIMER_funk(task22);};
Runnable task3 = () -> {DialogWindowkk("WOW you cool");};
Runnable task4 = () -> {DialogWindowkk("HAHAHAp");};

ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 for(int i=1; i<11; i++){

    service.submit(task3);

    service.submit(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    рр.cancel();
    return null;});

    service.submit(task1);

    service.submit(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(sleep1);
    рр.cancel();
    return null;});

    service.submit(task4);

    service.submit(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    рр.cancel();
    return null;});

    service.submit(task2);

    service.submit(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(sleep2);
    рр.cancel();return null;});  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit your dialog tasks to the event queue. For example:

`EventQueue.invokeLater(task3);` or `Platform.runLater(task3);` instead of `service.submit(task3);`

Comment: PlatformImpl.runAndWait(task3);  It works - THANKS YOU

Comment: You're welcome - please accept my answer! 

I'll change it to include the JavaFX style too.

Comment: Did you mean [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)?  Using com.sun.\* classes is not only unreliable (because they may be removed in future Java releases), it will be forbidden in Java 9.

Comment: @Sam You made my day twice today, my thanks for that. But hint: get rid of that -3 answer you have sitting there. Will even result in a badge (assuming its the first -3 posting of your you delete).